# I can't connect to my aws instance anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been running tomcat on my Amazon EC2 instance for a few weeks just fine but all of a sudden, I became unable to connect to it. When I use putty I can connect to it fine but when I try to connect with my browser by using ip:8080 , I can't connect anymore. I've tried restarting the instance (and of course, adjusting my input ip accordingly), restarting the tomcat server within the instance, and checking the security groups. Nothing seems to work. I have no idea why it stopped working out of the blue. How should I proceed?

Comment: Check your firewall rules. Make sure you're connecting from the outside on the correct IP address (do you have an elastic IP associated with the instance/should one be?) Are you connecting via DNS? Is it correctly setup? Can you connect to Tomcat locally when you Putty in? Run `netstat -an`. Is something listening on :8080?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to why you cannot connect. The best way to solve this is to follow Amazons troubleshooting tips, found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The amazon troubleshooting did not help. Then I remembered that I ad a line in my system32/driver/etc host file when I did some site migration.
Deleted that line and I was back in business again.

Hope that helped